# Update modification time of a file (touch)

Tags: r

How do I `touch` a file (i.e., update its modification time without changing its contents) in R? I'm looking for a cross-platform built-in (or packaged) equivalent of:

```
system2("touch", file_name)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See `?Sys.setFileTime`
In this case `Sys.setFileTime(path_to_file_or_directory, Sys.time())`  will presumably get the job done:

> On a Unix-alike it uses the system call ‘utimes’ if that is 
>   available, otherwise ‘utimes’.  On a POSIX file system it sets  both
>   the last-access and modification times.
>
> On Windows it uses the system call ‘SetFileTime’ to set the ‘last 
>   write time’.  Some Windows file systems only record the time at a 
>   resolution of two seconds.

Although I'm not sure how to reconcile "*it uses the system call ‘utimes’ if that is available, otherwise ‘utimes’*" with any meaningful statement.

Comment: Thanks. The documentation issue strikes me as odd, too. It looks like a misplaced `s`: https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/af607e72f8101f4262a666c5a16a40c4c2a99969/src/main/platform.c#L2923-L2934

Answer (score 5):

I have found [an implementation](https://github.com/HenrikBengtsson/R.utils/blob/master/R/touchFile.R#L43-L106) in the `R.utils` package, it utilizes the same pattern as suggested by @thelatemail but also offers vectorization and a fallback for R < 2.14, and invisibly returns the old timestamp:

```
R.utils::touchFile(file_name)
```

As usual, `library(sos); ???touch` was invaluable for finding this.